# Symbolic links, why doesn't this work:

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line, unix

```
me$ ln -s ~/x/y/ ~/Desktop/
ln: /Users/me/Desktop//: File exists
```

Why does this attempt at creating a symbolic link to `~/x/y`on the Desktop now work? The only way I can seem to get something like a symbolic link is this way:

```
ln -s * ~/Desktop/
```

I'm confused, this was really simple in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can do

```
ln -s ~/x/y ~/Desktop/
```

(note there's no slash '/' character after ~/x/y/).

I think the error message is not the most informative, but I understand it as that if you're putting a trailing slash, you're referring to the content of your directory (in this case ~/x/y), but if you omit it, you're referring to the directory itself.

Comment: Of course this one doesn't. You've done `ln -s ~/Desktop/symlink ~/Desktop/` which makes a symlink onto itself (there already is a ~/Desktop/symlink file in there, you can't link it to itself). If you do `ln -s ~/tmp/symlink ~/Desktop/` it should work.

Comment: Hmm, now it lets me make the symlink, but the symlink shows the default file icon (instead of the folder icon) and attempting to open the symlink [shows an error](http://f.cl.ly/items/29202T0T2M1e2K3w3R0Y/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-27%20at%2020.40.22.png)…

Comment: what type is the file that you're trying to make a link to? I've followed your initial sequence: `mkdir -p ~/x/y; ln -s ~/x/y ~/Desktop/` and all was created as expected, with a symlink Directory icon named `y` on my desktop. I can double-click that directory and it opens fine. Also, when I do `ls -la ~/Desktop/y` I get `lrwxr-xr-x  1 me  staff  15 27 Oct 20:47 /Users/me/Desktop/y@ -> /Users/me/x/y` in response. Can you show exactly the steps you've taken (ideally a full text capture of your terminal window)?

Comment: Again, can you paste in the commands and their output exactly as you've typed them? Difficult to tell without seeing them.

Comment: [Here's my Terminal output.](http://cl.ly/SAr6) Getting the same error as @Tor when attempting to open symlink.

Comment: Hmm... I'll be honest with you. I've done the exact same thing on my system (OSX 10.9) and it works perfectly... beats me!

Comment: Yeah, for me the problem was with an empty folder. But the folder with content worked fine. The latter is my "use case" so it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

`ln -s ~/x/y/ ~/Desktop/` attempts to symlink `~/Desktop/` to `~/x/y/`, which does not appear to be what you wanted, and is indeed not possible since `~/Desktop` exists (as the error states).

To create a symlink to `~/x/y/` inside `~/Desktop/`, you need to give it a name like so:

```
ln -s ~/x/y/ ~/Desktop/mysymlink
```

This creates a symlink `mysymlink` on your desktop that links to `~/x/y/`.